# What is the meaning of conversion rate for a free social networking site?

Tags: seo, conversions

First of all i am a newbie on SEO,conversion rates e.t.c

I have a free social networking website aimed to connect fellow muscians, and would like to know the meaning of conversion rates in my scenario. Is it correct to think,users clicking on the ads shown on my site as "conversions" ?

Google is already showing ads on my site, and i was looking some guidelines on improving conversion rates(making more users click on ads).

Whenever i searched for improving conversion rates,most of the results shows how to make users buy some stuff from your site e.t.c , thus the confusion.

Also google is showing the things that i browsed, on ads rather than show stuff
that is related to the content of my site. Is that how it works ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two somewhat unrelated questions and both are kind of broad. For this reason, I will keep the answer particularly short.

Conversion is often linked to sales because that is where the term comes from. As well, you are not supposed to encourage clicking on ads so no site is really going to talk about that. If you are looking for *improving adsense performance*, I suggest using the words in italics to better begin your search. Leave the term conversion out of your search. You can even just enter adsense in the search query text box and let Google make suggestions.

As well, ads can be content based or interest based. If a site is not yet fully understood by the ad network, then it will focus on interest based ads which would be based upon your surfing history. For Google, this can take a while even if they recently indexed your site. This is because another index that pertains to selling and presenting ads must be populated. The Internet is huge and even Google cannot index the whole thing within 10 months. So as a rule, it takes about a month before content based ads become a reality for most sites depending of course upon the size.

Comment: realized i was searching google with the wrong word, your "improving adsense performance" key words helped !

Comment: @user636525 Good!! I am glad! Pay attention to the date any content was written. This is because older advice may not be as timely. Pay attention to marketing sites that talk about monetizing websites. These are often the best place for information. However, there are some wing-nuts out there too so read a while before deciding what is realistic. I do not have any recommendations for you, but there are some terrific sites that can really help. Stay away from tricks and short-cuts. Go for solid advice. Cheers!!